# AWS IoT publish message to topic, and return nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-iot

I publish a message to AWS IoT (topic: mytest). The AWS IoT topic received the message as I expected, but I cannot get any response.

My code:

```
async function sendIot() {
    var params = {
      payload: JSON.stringify(body.msg),
      topic: "mytest",
      qos: 0 
    };

    console.log("Params::params: " + JSON.stringify(params));

    try {
        let iotPromise = await iotData.publish(params).promise();
        console.log('AWS IoT: resp: ' + JSON.stringify(iotPromise))
        return iotPromise;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error: " + e);
    }
  }
```

Response is an empty value

> `AWS IoT: resp: {}`

Is it normal or mistake from code? Any suggestion is appreciated.

***Edited***
Add "await" to promise

Answer (score 3):

What you are logging to the console is not the response but the promise. If you want to inspect the response within your function, you need to `await` it like so

```
async function sendIot() {
  const response = await iotData.publish(params).promise();
  console.log('AWS IoT: resp: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the "await", it still returns nothing

Answer (score 2):

**Response Elements**

Yes, by default response is empty object. If the action is successful, the service sends back an HTTP 200 response with an empty HTTP body.

Please refer the official link for more info https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_iotdata_Publish.html